# Want to set and get data with localstorage after google auth login

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-plus-signin

I am able to do login but I don't know how to set and get data into my localstorage, data is showing in alert.I know how to get and get result data from ajax response but did'nt understand how to do same with this below code.

```html
function getDataProfile() {
     var term = null;
     //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
     $.ajax({
         url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
         type: 'GET',
         data: term,
         dataType: 'json',
         error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {},
         success: function (data) {
             var item;
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
             // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
 localStorage.gmailLogin = "true";
             localStorage.gmailID = data.id;
             localStorage.gmailEmail = data.email;
             localStorage.gmailFirstName = data.given_name;
             localStorage.gmailLastName = data.family_name;
             localStorage.gmailProfilePicture = data.picture;
             localStorage.gmailGender = data.gender;

             $('#loginStatus').html(data.given_name);

         }
     });
    
 }
```

```js
var googleapi = {
     authorize: function (options) {
         var deferred = $.Deferred();
         //Build the OAuth consent page URL
         var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
             client_id: options.client_id,
             redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
             response_type: 'code',
             scope: options.scope
         });

         //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
         var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

         //The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
         //which sets the authorization code in the browser's title. However, we can't
         //access the title of the InAppBrowser.
         //
         //Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost", which means the
         //authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the url in the
         //loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart event, we can
         //find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after the user
         //has granted us access to their data.
         $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function (e) {
             var url = e.originalEvent.url;
             var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
             var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

             if (code || error) {
                 //Always close the browser when match is found
                 authWindow.close();

             }

             if (code) {
                 //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                 $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                     code: code[1],
                     client_id: options.client_id,
                     client_secret: options.client_secret,
                     redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                     grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                 }).done(function (data) {

                     deferred.resolve(data);

                     changepage('#adminhome');

                 }).fail(function (response) {
                     deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                     $("#errorStatus").html('error');
                 });
             } else if (error) {
                 //The user denied access to the app
                 //                 $("#mainerrorStatus").html(error);
                 //                 alert(error);
                 deferred.reject({
                     error: error[1]

                 });

             }

         });

         return deferred.promise();
     }
 };
 var accessToken;
 var UserData = null;

 function callGoogle() {

     //  alert('starting');
     googleapi.authorize({
         client_id: 'myid',
         client_secret: 'myid',
         redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
         scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
     }).done(function (data) {
         accessToken = data.access_token;
         // alert(accessToken);
         // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
         console.log(data.access_token);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
         getDataProfile();
         $("#accesstokenget").html('access token get');

     });

 }

 // This function gets data of user.
 function getDataProfile() {
     var term = null;
     //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
     $.ajax({
         url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
         type: 'GET',
         data: term,
         dataType: 'json',
         error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {},
         success: function (data) {
             var item;
             alert(JSON.stringify(data));
             // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
             localStorage.gmailLogin = "true";
             localStorage.gmailID = data.id;
             localStorage.gmailEmail = data.email;
             localStorage.gmailFirstName = data.given_name;
             localStorage.gmailLastName = data.family_name;
             localStorage.gmailProfilePicture = data.picture;
             localStorage.gmailGender = data.gender;

             $('#loginStatus').html(data.given_name);

         }
     });
     disconnectUser();
 }

 function disconnectUser() {
     var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;

     // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: revokeUrl,
         async: false,
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success: function (nullResponse) {
             // Do something now that user is disconnected
             // The response is always undefined.
             accessToken = null;
             //             alert(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
             console.log("-----signed out..!!----" + accessToken);

         },
         error: function (e) {
             // Handle the error
             // console.log(e);
             // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
             // https://plus.google.com/apps
             //             alert('user diconnected<br>could not be connected');
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: This is what you want  [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to use localStorage:

// Store

```
localStorage.setItem("gmailLogin", "true");
```

// Retrieve

```
var isGmailLogin = localStorage.getItem("gmailLogin");
```